# How to center SearchBar with one button on header NativeBase

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, native-base

Trying to center the searchbar with menu button in right on header using nativebase. Code has been given below:

```html
    <Header>
        <Body>
            <Button style={styles.searchButton} onPress={() => this.onSearchPress()} >
             <Text>Search Service</Text>
           </Button>
        </Body>
        <Right>
            <Icon name='menu' style={styles.drawerIcon} onPress={()=> navigation.openDrawer()} />
        </Right>
    </Header>
```

How to position it center with full width?

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <Header>
      <Left/>
        <Body>
            <Button style={styles.searchButton} onPress={() => this.onSearchPress()} >
             <Text>Search Service</Text>
           </Button>
        </Body>
        <Right>
            <Icon name='menu' style={styles.drawerIcon} onPress={()=> navigation.openDrawer()} />
        </Right>
    </Header>
```

Comment: there is reserved space for both right and left if you can check that in header file